# Function Callback from Object-C to C++ with parameter on cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, callback, cocos2d-x

I have a project cocos2d-x on IOS , with 1 scene to login, 1 scene to post picture to facebook:
When click 1 button from scene 1, it will login to facebook and get userID, and on function sessionStateChanged on AppController it's will call 1 function of scene1 and return userID . At scene 2 when click button , it will post picture to wall of user. And problem it's how can function sesssionStateChanged on AppController know do function of scene1 or scene 2? 
If on Android, it's have a native function like is:

on java:

```
private static native void getFriendList(String _userID, String _friendList);
```

on C++

```
        extern "C"
{
    void Java_com_bestteam_ipostionchess_iPositionChess_getFriendList(JNIEnv *env,jobject thiz,jstring _userid,jstring _friendList){
        ///
    }
}
```

Anybody can give me solution? Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

objectiveC and c++ codes can be mixed ,you just set the file type as "Default Objective-c++ source"
[image: change file type]

and change the file name from .m to .mm

then you can just call c++ function from your AppController.mm

Comment: Thanks for your help, I get the solution :)